# Removing duplicate values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm adding several id's to an array when a checkbox is checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" onClick={() => this.addEvcGroupToArray(item.stations.map((item, key) => { return (item.stationID) }))}
```

This is the function that adds the ids to the array

```
     addEvcGroupToArray(id) {
        console.log("group_id ",id);
        var stationId = {};
        id.map((item, key) => {
            stationId = {
                stationId: item
            }
        })
        var evcGroupIdArray = this.state.stationIdArray.concat(stationId);
        this.setState({ stationIdArray: evcGroupIdArray })
    }
```

For example `console.log("group_id ",id);`  outputs an array of ids like `["8"]` (Here it's just one id,but this can be any number of ids). I want to prevent adding the same id's if the user click on the checkbox again.

I tried something like this using `Set`. But it did not work. How can i do this?

```
  addEvcGroupToArray(id) {
    console.log("group_id ",id);
    var stationId = {};
    id.map((item, key) => {
        stationId = {
            stationId: item
        }
    })
    var evcGroupIdArray = this.state.stationIdArray.concat(stationId);
    var uniqueArray = [...new Set(evcGroupIdArray)];
    this.setState({ stationIdArray: uniqueArray })
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with React, however,why do you use `map` without assiging `id.map`?

Answer (score 1):

First initialize an array instead of an object like

```
let stationId = [];
```

After try adding this instead of adding id.map

```
id.forEach(item => {
  if (!this.state.stationIdArray.some(item => item === id)) {
   stationId.push(item);
 } 
})
```

and set the state

```
this.setState({ stationIdArray: [...stationIdArray, stationId] });
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

map already returns an array, it is not recommended to use it to loop through values although you can do it.

```js
const myArr = [
  {stationId: 3},
  {stationId: 1},
  {stationId: 2},
  {stationId: 3},
  {stationId: 3},
];


const result = [];
const map = new Map();
for (const item of myArr) {
if(!map.has(item.stationId)){
    map.set(item.stationId, true);    // set any value to Map
    result.push({
        stationId: item.stationId
    });
}
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

lodash `_.uniqueBy` can be applied on `evcGroupIdArray`.

```
_.uniqBy(evcGroupIdArray, 'stationId');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning id array just before going into the rest of the logic

```
addEvcGroupToArray (id) {
  console.log("group_id ", id);
  const clean = new Set(id); // <- remove duplicated ids
  var stationId = {};
  clean.map((item, key) => {
    stationId = {
      stationId: item
    };
  });
  var evcGroupIdArray = this.state.stationIdArray.concat(stationId);
  this.setState({ stationIdArray: evcGroupIdArray });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function addEvcGroupToArray(id) {
    console.log("group_id ",id);
    // Get the current state id array
    const { stationIdArray } = this.state;
    // Append new id array
    const uniqueArray = [...new Set([...stationIdArray, ...id])];
    this.setState({ stationIdArray: uniqueArray })
}
```